# How to select records from all pages in table?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mantine

I'm using the Mantine DataTable library which has a lot of native features by default.

I only found ways to select records by page and not by all pages. I could not do the functionality manually.

Could you help me with some way to make this work?

**Codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/red-shadow-lrsvf6?file=/src/App.js